# Console.log Refuses to Print Statements in Mutation File

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, console.log

I am using a PostgreSQL database, with a GraphQL / NodeJS server. One of the mutations is giving me extensive problems, due to its intrinsically complex nature. I am trying to use `console.log` statements throughout so I can track the data, but not a SINGLE statement prints. Now, before you all jump on me and say that the mutation probably isn't getting hit, that's not the case. I'm getting return values, the mutation is occurring (I checked the Network section of the Browser to confirm. I also have error handlers that do not get triggered) but nothing gets printed.
The code for one of the two mutations called simultaneously is as follows...

```
import db from "../../../../utils/generatePrisma.js";
import checkOwnerAuth from "../../../../utils/checkAuthorization/check-owner-auth.js";
import checkManagerAuth from "../../../../utils/checkAuthorization/check-manager-auth.js";

export default {
    Mutation: {
        scorecardToolCreateWeeklyReports: async (_, {
            token,
            dspId,
            role,
            transporterId,
            date,
            feedbackStatus,
            feedbackMessage,
            feedbackMessageSent,
            rank,
            tier,
            delivered,
            keyFocusArea,
            fico,
            seatbeltOffRate,
            speedingEventRate,
            distractionsRate,
            followingDistanceRate,
            signalViolationsRate,
            deliveryCompletionRate,
            deliveredAndRecieved,
            photoOnDelivery,
            attendedDeliveryAccuracy,
            dnr,
            podOpps,
            ccOpps
        }, context) => {
            let owner;
            let manager;


            if (role === 'OWNER') {
                owner = await checkOwnerAuth(token)
            }

            if (role === 'MANAGER') {
                manager = await checkManagerAuth(token)
            }

            const foundDriver = await db.driver.findFirst({
                where: {
                    transporterId: transporterId,
                    dspId: dspId
                }
            })

            if (!foundDriver) {
                throw new Error('Driver does not exist')
            }

            console.log("\n-----------------------\n Found Driver in scoreCardToolCreateWeeklyReport")
            console.log(foundDriver)

            try {
                return await db.weeklyReport.create({
                    data: {
                        driver: {
                            connect: {
                                id: foundDriver.id
                            }
                        },
                        date: date,
                        feedbackStatus: feedbackStatus,
                        feedbackMessage: feedbackMessage,
                        feedbackMessageSent: feedbackMessageSent,
                        rank: rank,
                        tier: tier,
                        delivered: delivered,
                        keyFocusArea: keyFocusArea,
                        fico: fico,
                        seatbeltOffRate: seatbeltOffRate,
                        speedingEventRate: speedingEventRate,
                        distractionsRate: distractionsRate,
                        followingDistanceRate: followingDistanceRate,
                        signalViolationsRate: signalViolationsRate,
                        deliveryCompletionRate: deliveryCompletionRate,
                        deliveredAndRecieved: deliveredAndRecieved,
                        photoOnDelivery: photoOnDelivery,
                        attendedDeliveryAccuracy: attendedDeliveryAccuracy,
                        dnr: dnr,
                        podOpps: podOpps,
                        ccOpps: ccOpps
                    }
                }).then( (resolved) => {
                    console.log(resolved)
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("\n---------------\n Error in WeeklyReportCreation")
                console.log(error)
                throw new Error(error)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, the return I recieve is exactly what I would want and would expect, however, it does not persist, and on any refresh, rerender, or movement between pages and there's no model, its like the mutation just never even happened. When the mutation is called from the Frontend, it runs somewhat as expected. Upon hitting `inspect` on the browser and looking at the response section in the Network tab, I get the following...

```
{"data":
{"scorecardToolCreateWeeklyReports":
{"id":"91c7dd10-0af8-4fc7-9906-20643700c97f",
"createdAt":"2022-04-12T18:09:09.787Z",
"date":"11-24-22",
"hadAccident":false,
"feedbackMessage":"null",
"feedbackMessageSent":false,
"feedbackStatus":"Fantastic",
"acknowledged":false,
"acknowledgedAt":null,
"rank":1,
"tier":"Fantastic",
"delivered":116,
"keyFocusArea":"null",
"fico":"850",
"seatbeltOffRate":"Coming Soon",
"speedingEventRate":"Coming Soon",
"distractionsRate":"Coming Soon",
"followingDistanceRate":"Coming Soon",
"signalViolationsRate":"Coming Soon",
"deliveryCompletionRate":"100",
"deliveredAndRecieved":"100",
"photoOnDelivery":"100",
"attendedDeliveryAccuracy":0,
"dnr":0,
"podOpps":54,
"ccOpps":0,
"__typename":"WeeklyReport"}}}
```

The mutation shown before is then placed into a minor resolver...

```
import GraphQLJSON from "graphql-type-json";
import scorecardToolCreateDriverAccounts from "./mutations/scorecardToolCreateDriverAccounts.js";
import scorecardToolCreateWeeklyReports from "./mutations/scorecardToolCreateWeeklyReports.js";

export default {
    Query: {

    },
    Mutation: {
        ...scorecardToolCreateDriverAccounts.Mutation,
        ...scorecardToolCreateWeeklyReports.Mutation
    },
    JSON: GraphQLJSON
}
```

And then this minor resolver is then imported into the main resolver

```
import GraphQLJSON from 'graphql-type-json';

// NEW RESOLVERS
import ownerReslovers from './owner/ownerResolvers.js';
import managerResolvers from './manager/managerResolvers.js';
import driverResolvers from './driver/driverResolvers.js';
import dspResolvers from './dsp/dspResolvers.js';
import weeklyReportResolvers from './weeklyReport/weeklyReportResolvers.js';
import scorecardResolvers from './scorecardTool/scorecardResolvers.js';
import chatroomResolvers from './chatrooms/chatroomResolvers.js';
import shiftPlannerResolvers from './shiftPlanner/shiftPlannerResolvers.js';
import messagesResolvers from './messages/messagesResolvers.js';
import accidentResolvers from './accidents/accidentResolvers.js';
import shiftPlannerDatesResolvers from './shiftPlannerDates/shiftPlannerDatesResolvers.js';
import shiftResolvers from './shift/shiftReolvers.js';

// ADDITIONAL RESOLVERS
import additionalResolvers from './additional/additionalResolvers.js';

export default {
    Query: {
        ...ownerReslovers.Query,
        ...managerResolvers.Query,
        ...driverResolvers.Query,
        ...dspResolvers.Query,
        ...weeklyReportResolvers.Query,
        ...shiftPlannerResolvers.Query,
        ...chatroomResolvers.Query,
        ...messagesResolvers.Query,
        ...accidentResolvers.Query,
        ...shiftPlannerDatesResolvers.Query,
        ...shiftResolvers.Query,

        ...scorecardResolvers.Query,
        ...additionalResolvers.Query
    },
    Mutation: {
        ...ownerReslovers.Mutation,
        ...managerResolvers.Mutation,
        ...driverResolvers.Mutation,
        ...dspResolvers.Mutation,
        ...weeklyReportResolvers.Mutation,
        ...shiftPlannerResolvers.Mutation,
        ...chatroomResolvers.Mutation,
        ...messagesResolvers.Mutation,
        ...accidentResolvers.Mutation,
        ...shiftPlannerDatesResolvers.Mutation,
        ...shiftResolvers.Mutation,

        ...scorecardResolvers.Mutation,
        ...additionalResolvers.Mutation
    },
    JSON: GraphQLJSON,
}
```

Comment: Has something overwritten `console.log`? Do you get other logs?

Comment: "*I'm getting return values, the mutation is occurring*" - what return values does the client get? Where do they come from? I'd guess that while the mutation itself may run, it's not *this implementation* that you expect.

Comment: @Bergi No, I've only ever used `console.log` so I don't know how it could have gotten overwritten

Comment: Are you sure you're using a mutation and not a query? "*the return I recieve is exactly what I would want*" - well that value couldn't be the result of the `scorecardToolCreateWeeklyReports` code you've shown, `return await ….then( (resolved) => { console.log(resolved) })` only ever returns (a promise for) `undefined` and not the object - it only logs it.

Comment: The return wasn't from a `console.log` it came from inspecting the browser and looking at the Network tab, under response

Comment: Please show us the query text that generates this result, and also show us the code where the exported value (`{Mutation: …}`) is used

Comment: Added the extra information into the main question as an edit

Comment: Try to place a breakpoint in the main resolver module, inspect the 
value `scorecardResolvers`: does it actually contain the method you expect? With a *[[source]]* in the module that you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Bergi

Comment: It's quite clear now that the function you posted, the one that contains the `console.log` statements, is not being called. Why that is, you'll need to debug.

Comment: It is being called, otherwise I wouldn't be getting a response that isnt an error

Comment: For reference, if I intentionally break it so that it doesn't get called, I get a much different response

Comment: No it's not called. You're cannot get that response from the code you posted; you must be getting it from somewhere else. Please use a debugger, place a breakpoint in the code, and you'll see that it isn't called.

Comment: How do I use a debugger here? I'm not exactly sure how to add a breakpoint to a resolver file which runs asynchronously

Comment: [Attach a debugger to node](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/), set your breakpoint, then hit that endpoint with your graphql request. Also you might want to place breakpoints and do step-by-step execution in your schema (resolver) building code, since that's the most likely location of the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my final thought was correct. The mutation is 100% being run, and the log statements are being hit.
The issue is due to AWS EC2 CodePipeline deployment. The backend server is perpetually being run on AWS's end, so the `console` where the logs occur is no longer my VSC terminal, but the instance's AWS console.
This is also the same with the front end, where if I run the code locally, none of the new logs get hit. I can only see ALL of the frontend logs if I am on the IP adress in the browser, not the localhost.
This all being said, I currently have no idea how to view the console in AWS and if anyone was privy to that information and cared to share that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Upon further investigation, if on CI/CD Deployment to EC2, you lose access to all print logs.